# Windows OS – Can’t close the “How do you want to open this file?” dialog

Tags: windows-10

I cannot get the “How do you want to open this file?” dialog to close. I don’t have any windows or explorers open. It stays in front of other windows so is blocking my view. How do I get this window to go away?

[image]

Comment: Uncheck "Always use this App ..."  and then you should be able to close it,

Comment: Your question is unclear. You want this dialog open, but the dialog IS open and is covering things? What is your actual problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Go to the Task Manger
2. Go to the ‘Users tab’
3. Expand the dropdown
4. You should see an app called, ‘Pick an app’. Right click on this item and select from menu, ‘End task’

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to close the "Open With" window - hit the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key.

Comment: Unfortunately, for me in Windows 10 - 21H2 this did not work, but the task manager did.  I don't know why.